# ASP equivalent to isset($_POST)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, colorbox

I have a Colorbox that opens on a page after the document finishes loading. The problem is I only want it to load if someone has clicked through from a link. I would do this in PHP with form POST or GET variables but the site is built in ASP and it's a framework that I can't alter from an e-commerce site.

I tried to see if there was an equivalent to if isset($_POST) in ASP but there doesn't seem to be one. Is there a way to do this in ASP?

```
<% IF (Request.Form("clicked")="clicked") %>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery.colorbox({
    iframe      : true,
    innerWidth  : 430,
    innerHeight : 208,
    href        : "/v/browse_market.asp"
  });
});
</script>
<%ELSE%>
<%END IF%>
```

Is this close? I have a form on another page that submits a hidden post variable with the name="clicked" and the value="clicked" to this page. It still seems to be showing always (whether I click through or not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IF (request.form("element") <> "") THEN`  is the proper way in asp (classic)
`if(Request.Form["element"] <> "")` is the proper way in ASP.NET

Comment: I edited my code above. Thanks for putting me in the right direction. It's still not working, am I on the right track?